# React how to use refs to focus/blur?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm reading the React documentation from Reactjs.org but it doesn't seem to be working for what I want to do.

I want to render a component with nested divs. Upon clicking each of its nested divs, it turns into an input. Upon clicking outside of the specific div, it transforms the input back into a div.

I wanted to use refs with blur/focus to achieve this but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work.

This is what my component looks like so far, which is a child component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
}
focusRef = () => {
    this.textInput.current.focus();
}
focusEvent = () => {
    console.log("focus event.");
}
render() {
    let item = <div
        className="item-class"
        ref={this.textInput}
        onFocus={this.showIt}
        onClick={this.focusRef}>Item Name</div>
    return(<div>{item}</div>)
}
```

Looking at the sample code provided by [react.js.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), I'm wondering why there is no onFocus event. Is that not required? How else will an event be triggered when the element receives focus? In my code, `focusRef` is triggered but `focusEvent` is not, which is also something I can't figure out. Secondly, how can I detect blur/losing focus, so I can swap my input back to a div? Lastly, I am confused as to how focus/blur events that swap an element between div and input can work with rendering, won't I need to rerender every time this swap occurs, AKA every time an element receives/loses focus? Doesn't that require needing to maintain focus of the elements (or lack thereof) between renders?

I would prefer a solution that does not involve hooks, if possible.

Comment: Focus works on `input` not on `div`. Trying changing `div` to `input`

Answer (score 1):

In order for a `div` element to be focusable it needs to be made interactable. Add a tab index to the div so it can be given focus.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div 
        tabIndex={0} 
        onFocus={() => console.log('focus')} 
        onBlur={() => console.log('blur')}
      >
        Click or tab to me!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is a toggleable/focusable div/input. It uses state to hold whether or not a div or input should be rendered, and a ref and `componentDidUpdate` method to ***refocus*** on the input after switching up the view.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  textInputRef = React.createRef();

  state = {
    isInput: false,
    value: "test"
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { isInput } = this.state;
    isInput && this.textInputRef.current.focus();
  }

  handleFocus = () => {
    console.log("focus");
    this.setState({ isInput: true });
  };

  handleBlur = () => {
    console.log("blur");
    this.setState({ isInput: false });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });

  render() {
    const { isInput, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {isInput ? (
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={this.textInputRef}
            value={value}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        ) : (
          <div tabIndex={0} onFocus={this.handleFocus}>
            {value}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I see, I never heard of tab indexing before. Regardless your example helped me understand some things. I will try to implement something similar.

Comment: @JonathanYap Even though you should try to limit your SO posts to a single specific question/issue I'm working on a codesandbox implementing the toggleable div/input since  I find this an interesting idea.

Comment: @JonathanYap Updated answer with *a* working solution to what you seek. Please do check it out and see what you think.